# Put Ubuntu on an HP ENVY with Beats audio. Everything works except the sound

Tags: sound, hp

Just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my HP ENVY to replace Windows 10. I really love it. The only problem is that the audio from the built in speakers sounds really muffled. I tried fixing the problem by using this solution I found threads on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/) and many solutions similar to it, but nothing worked. I decided to cut my losses and just use my external speakers, but even though the speakers are connected, the audio came out of the computer speakers. I just made the switch to Linux and everything seems awesome, Ubuntu blows Windows 10 out of the water, but this issue with the sound is really irksome.

My laptop: 
[http://www.amazon.com/HP-17-j130us-17-3-Inch-Touchsmart-Laptop/dp/B00H7O3VI0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H7O3VI0)

My speakers: 
Simple Audio Listen Bluetooth speakers.

I was connected directly via USB, not Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound stupid but:

Did you try and click the speaker icon at the top right and choosing sound settings.

Click on the adapter / output you want.

I noticed i had to click on my HDMI even though its highlighted on every fresh install.

Comment: I did try that many times. I have choice between two outputs: Speakers and LADSPA plugin multiband EQ built in audio analog stereo. There's no difference between the two. Has no effect on the quality of the sound.